# ошибка в соединении с базой данных c Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Здавствуйте возник такой вопрос. гуглил пытался найти решение но пока безрезультатно может вы подскажите

```
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Windows;
    namespace Fuel_Monitoring_Form_1._1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>



    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {



        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FillDataGrid();
        }



        private void FillDataGrid()
        {
            //string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
            //string CmdString = string.Empty;
            string conString = "Data Sourse = nameServerDB; User Id = login; Password = pass; Initial Catalog = nameDB;";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {

              string CmdString =
                    "Select top 10  EQUIP_IDENT, TIMESTAMP, FUEL_LEVEL from FUEL_LEVEL_TRANS order by TIMESTAMP desc";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Employee");

                con.Open();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                grdEmployee.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                con.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Вот код Xaml :

```
    <Window x:Class="Fuel_Monitoring_Form_1._1.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="White">
        <Grid>
            <DataGrid Name="grdEmployee" Background="White" Margin="0,63,0,0"></DataGrid>
        </Grid>    
    </Window>
```

компиляции выдает "No Sourse Avaliable/ No symbols are loaded for any call stack..."
 и вот еще

> 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'Fuel_Monitoring_Form_1._1.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.

я понимаю что что то нитак с Xaml , но не пойму что. А когда прохожусть Breackpoint'ом то крашит на

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
```

подскажите может кто сталкивался...

Comment: В пароле есть какие-нибудь спецсимволы? Например space, =, " ?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, шоустоппер где-то в ConnectionString. Я бы для начала привел CS в соответствие с общепринятыми стандартами, удалил бы trailing spaces.

> ConnectionString – не место для творчества :)

Потом проверил бы присутствие спецсимволов в пароле. Если, например в пароле сидит " (кавычка) или = (равно), то они портят праздник.

Самый эффективный способ отладки CS – создать ее с нуля и протестировать штатными средствами ODBC. А потом скопировать рабочую строку в проект.

Comment: Спасибо, я воспльзуюсь советом.